# vertical alignment with auto resize image to fit within the carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel and I can't show the images correctly. How do I position an image at the bottom of carousel?

This is my mobile view, works perfectly, no zoom is needed:
[image]

But when I choose the full screen view, the image expands to top:

[image]

And I'm interesting with this:

[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
        <!--Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--Photos-->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="../sources/img/carousel/01.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../sources/img/carousel/02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../sources/img/carousel/03.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../sources/img/carousel/04.jpg">
            </div>
            <!--Carousel controls-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--Container carousel-->
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
  max-height: 700px;
}
.carousel-inner > .item img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following CSS should fix the problem.

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    height: 25vh;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

You might have to change the `height` of `.item` using media query.